# How can I change the font of the captions in NSIS?

Tags: fonts, dialog, nsis, caption

I am trying to change the font of the captions in NSIS, and I am looking for script lines that change the font of the captions in NSIS.

Comment: Which element do you mean by caption? The window titlebar or the modern UI header?

Comment: Everything possible, like the big title in the welcome and finish dialogs, the header in other dialogs, the content labels, the buttons, the checkboxes, the radio boxes, the combo boxes, the text boxes, and the lists. Yes, I am talking about Modern UI.

Comment: I thing I found a way to do it collectively. For example, if I want the font of all captions to be Arial, I can just write " SetFont "Arial" 8 ". However, I want also want to know how to change the font of each caption individually.

Answer (score 1):

`SetFont` sets the base font used by the UI. MUI creates some custom fonts but base them on the ^Font and ^FontSize lang-strings set by `SetFont`. Colors are separate from the font and are set with a couple of MUI defines and `SetCtlColors`.

If you want custom fonts (different from `SetFont`) in various places then you must set them yourself manually:

```
SetFont "Comic Sans MS" 9
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT MyGuiInit
!define MUI_TEXTCOLOR 00AAAA
!define MUI_BGCOLOR FFAAAA

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW onCompsShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU SMP $9
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

var MyFont

Function MyGuiInit
IntOp $2 $(^FontSize) + 5
CreateFont $1 "Impact" "$2"
SendMessage $mui.Header.Text ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1
CreateFont $MyFont "Terminal" "$(^FontSize)"
SendMessage $mui.Header.SubText ${WM_SETFONT} $MyFont 1
FunctionEnd

Function onCompsShow
SendMessage $mui.ComponentsPage.Text ${WM_SETFONT} $MyFont 1
FunctionEnd
```